# MongoDB JSON Validation did not pass

Tags: json, mongodb, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, mongodb-shell

I created a very basic counter collection with a validator. I also put a method to call it. In the method, I have a findAndModify function to update sequence. When I call it it doesn't pass the validator only if I change its level as MODERATE. What is the problem here?

**This is my validator scheme.**

```
db.createCollection('counter', {
   validator: {
     $jsonSchema: {
       bsonType: 'object',
       required: ['sequence_value'],
       properties: {
         sequence_value: {
           bsonType: 'int'
         }
       }
     }
   }
 });
```

**This is autoupdate function.**

```
function getValueForNextSequence(sequenceOfName) {
    var sequenceDoc = db.counter.findAndModify({
        query: { _id: sequenceOfName },
        update: { $inc: { sequence_value: 1 } },
        new: true
    });
    return sequenceDoc.sequence_value;
}
```

**This is the shell command I have insert to call it.**

```
db.user.insert({
    _id: getValueForNextSequence("user_id"),
    name: "Heggo",
    surname: "Ruffo",
    phone: "5879885858",
    roles: ["Logistic"],
    password: "d1e8a70b5ccab1dc2f56bbf7e99f064a660c08e361a35751b9c483c88943d082"
})
```

**And the output log...**

```
2020-03-09T13:12:48.559+0300 E QUERY    [js] Error: findAndModifyFailed failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Document failed validation",
        "code" : 121,
        "codeName" : "DocumentValidationFailure"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCollection.prototype.findAndModify@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:736:1
getValueForNextSequence@(shell):2:23
@(shell):1:1
```